# MySQL File or Directory not Found ODBC

Tags: mysql, vb.net, file, directory

I am writing a program which deals with data transformations via MySQL and it deals with big files.

I [made a question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162101/backgroundworker-not-running-when-its-needed/38162270?noredirect=1#comment63753230_38162270) about another issue I was having, while I was trying out someone's answer I got the following error

```
[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.1.9-MariaDB]File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ingram\' not found (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
```

I am certain that directory exists and when I change the code to its original state it works perfectly.

What is going on there?

This is the piece of code that gives me the problem

```
Cmd.CommandText = String.Format("LOAD DATA INFILE ""{0}"" IGNORE INTO TABLE libros_nueva FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '""' ESCAPED BY '""' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';", filepath)
 Cmd.Execute()
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Remove the trailing \ from the location and see what it does.

Comment: If you use the MySql DB providers you can specify those elements as properties using `MySqlBulkLoader`.  What is there looks like it is missing the file name?

Comment: Hmm, first time I heard of this. I am reading the source of Bulk Loader, but can't quite comprehend it. Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: As @Plutonix said, What is the value of _filepath_? I think you need to pass a filename but from the error message it seems that only a folder is passed there

Comment: The problem does not reside in filepath, it resides on the database file path. It shows 'C:\xampp\....'

Comment: When more than one person comments, you need to add `@` to the name  when you want that person to get pinged.  I only saw this because @Steve (like that) pinged me.  If you are doing transforms, bulk import/insert seems to be the wrong way to go.  CSVHelper provides a very economical way to import 1 at a time so you can do stuff.  I find the SQL import syntax much more convoluted than `MySqlBulkLoader`

Comment: If the answer posted helped solve the issue, please click the checkmark so this is removed from the Unanswered list.  If the `MySqlBulkLoader` you requested helped, please upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the salient portion of the error message:

> File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ingram\' not found (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")

I am pretty sure you are passing just a path when a full path and file name are required.  There is certainly no file name in the path it echoed back.

---

*Can you please explain it [`MySqlBulkLoader`] to me?*

Another way to import is to use `MySqlBulkLoader` from the `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` namespace:

```vb
    ' columns in the order they appear in the CSV file:
    Dim cols As String() = {"Name", "Descr", "`Group`", "ValueA",
                        "Bird", "Fish", "zDate", "Color", "Active"}
    Dim csvFile As String = "C:\Temp\mysqlImport.csv"
    Dim rows As Int32

    Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(MySQLConnStr)
        Dim bulk = New MySqlBulkLoader(dbcon)

        bulk.TableName = "importer"    
        bulk.FieldTerminator = ","      ' this is a CSV
        bulk.LineTerminator = "\r\n"    ' == CR/LF
        bulk.FileName = csvFile         ' full file path name to CSV 
        bulk.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 0    ' has a header?

        bulk.Columns.Clear()
        For Each s In cols
            bulk.Columns.Add(s)         ' tell MySQL the order
        Next

        rows = bulk.Load()              ' Make it so.
    End Using
```

Times to import 100k rows: 3619, 2719 and 2987 ms.  There is also a `LoadAsync` method which may be of interest given your last question.

If there are data transforms to do *before* the insert, `CSVHelper` can provide an easy way to load records so you can do whatever needs to be done, then use normal SQL Inserts to update the DB.

---

Part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37735839/1070452) shows using `CSVHelper` to import into Access in batches of 50k and which was pretty fast.